# How does Sqoop fetch metadata of tables mentioned in --query option?

Tags: mapreduce, sqoop, hadoop2

As per "Apache Sqoop Cookbook", by using query imports, Sqoop can’t use the database catalog to fetch the metadata.

Then how does Sqoop fetch metadata of tables (cities & normcities) mentioned in query option? eg:

`--query "SELECT cities.city AS first_city normcities.city AS second_city FROM cities LEFT JOIN normcities USING(id)"`

Comment: quoting from same page/book: "During initial preparation and before submitting the MapReduce job, Sqoop performs several actions. One such action is to fetch metadata about the transferred columns and their associated types. During this step, Sqoop will generate a Java class that contains one attribute for each column that will be named as the column itself. Java attributes must be unique; therefore, all columns in your query must have unique names." - https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/apache-sqoop-cookbook/9781449364618/ch04.html

Comment: But how Sqoop fetch metadata about the transferred columns and their associated types without using the database catalog?

Comment: you can use java files that sqoop creates. sqoop will create java files under dir from where you run sqoop command - or you can specify this `--outdir <dir>` - Output directory for generated code - option to store at specific location

Comment: java files are nothing but POJO classe(s) for imported table(s)